# Hardware write and read function for linux

Tags: c, linux, performance

What would be the equivalent function i could choose in LINUX as compared to below DOS calls ?

```
inportb(x) 
outportb(x,v)
```

Thanks
Brijesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing only port I/O then you can use [ioperm](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ioperm) to change permissions and then use [in*/out*](http://linux.die.net/man/2/outb) from user space. Obviously user permissions still apply.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inb() and outb()` calls. Go [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/IO-Port-Programming-2.html) you'll find more information how to use it.